# Ginkgo: how to combine test reports

Tags: go, gitlab, gitlab-ci, ginkgo

I'm setting up GitLab CI.
We use Ginkgo tests for BDD.
Ginkgo creates a report per each folder where tests are located.

This create a problem with collecting all reports and publishing it as a single test report file.

Is it possible to configure GinkGo in a such way so I could take all test in a single test report file?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is your reports lies in each test folder:
Example

```
testScripts
 - test_1_directory (contains test spec and result files)
 - test_2_directory (contains test spec and result files)
 - test_3_directory (contains test spec and result files)
```

I'm not sure this might exactly help you but can give it a try

In you job add reports paths as mentioned below:

```
artifacts:
    reports:
      junit:
        - ./packages/e2e/goProject/testScripts/**/**.xml
```

Assuming .xml are report generated.

At the end all test will be displayed in pipeline's test section
[image]